# android - Is logcat logging synchronous or asynchronous

Tags: android, performance

Does adb logcat logging with `Log.i("TAG", "...")` occur synchronously or asynchronously.

I want to measure the impact of Logging on my app performance.
I want to know the internal details of Log api in android. Whether it writes to logcat stream in the same thread or is it done asynchronously.

And also how often are the logcat logs flushed on disk. Does the flushing occur from the app process or is there a separate process that does the flushing.

Comment: Did you find a solution here?

Comment: Didn't get time to go through the source code. Will update the post once I find out.

Answer (score 0):

Seems to be synchronous.

A point to start searching could be the native Android [logging code](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/core/jni/android_util_Log.cpp).